# Auto incrementing field name in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to build an app where you can, among other things, make a meal plan. I'm working on the version where you make a plan for a month. I'm using Django, writing in python, and using SQLite as my database.
The problem I have is regarding user input and databases. Instead of making a form with 30 fields, I want to make one with a single field that changes its name for each time the user has entered a response.

An example of this would be something like this:

The first time the user enters an input:
Meal day 1:_______

The second time:
Meal day 2:______

In simple terms, I want the integer in the field name to change.

Here's some pseudo code, it might be a mix of C# and python atm:

```
"Day " + x
x=1
if x < 30
   display add button
   x++
elif x == 30
   display add button
   display the confirm button
   x++
elif x == 31
   display only the confirm button
else x > 31
   x = 31
```

Can anyone give me a template for something like this, or point me in the right direction with a function/word I can search for that helps me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want integer in the name field to change. Why dont you simple make a  new integer field and  append it with your name at your template?

You should make an integer field in your model (say "DayNo") with default value=0. Then you have the day number 0 initially and when user enters first response, simply increase the DayNo and display a new form using JS/Jquert with updated DayNo (no need to request anything from backend). Whenever user clicks on submit just update the DayNo field with the new value. Also, if you want to save the information without reloading the page then use jquery ajax calls.

Comment: Honestly, being as new to this as I am, I had to do a bit of trying and failing before getting this to work. But, following this approach worked. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Kindly mark my answer as correct